# Russian citizen with Belgian residency permit enter UK for holiday with UK citizen partner. Visa?

Tags: visas, family, residency

I am a UK citizen living in Belgium on a residency permit (5 yr). My partner is a Russian citizen, who has a 1 yr Belgian residency permit.
We are applying for co-habitition in Belgium.

What visa/documentation does my partner require to enter the UK with me? The UK Gov website isn't very helpful and want to charge me 6 gbp to send them an email!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your partner having a Belgian residence permit is not directly relevant.

<s>You *may* be entitled to bring her with you to the UK under freedom-of-movement rules, but if you're not married that depends on whether you're deemed to have a "durable relationship". Typically several years of shared residence will be expected. If you think you qualify, the way forward is to apply for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh) in advance.</s>

Hmm, actually it appears that the UK government does not recognize unmarried partners at all under "Surinder Singh" applications (i.e. when the union citizen is a British citizen who has moved to another member state). That is [currently being challenged in the ECJ](https://curia.europa.eu/jcms/jcms/p1_953216/en/), but the court has yet to rule.

She needs to apply for a standard visitor visa and qualify for it based on her own circumstances.